# Remote Server Terminal of for specific Applications

Tags: node.js, remote-access

I have a server and i want my colleague to access only the application terminal of a specific application or console log the errors or anything he wants to log. I have used console.re, a remote console client, but i couldnot access it from my own machine; It somehow works on brower of the client but not elsewhere. I want something that could solve this problem. BTW i use node js application if there is any package that could resolve this i would be really thankful.

Thank you,